# If I insert my Pokemon Black 2 cartridge into another 3DS will the save file be deleted?

Tags: pokemon-black-2-white-2

I'm meaning to buy a new 3DS, and I'm worried if I insert my Pokemon Black 2 cartridge into the new one all my progress will be lost. I don't want waste my money buying another copy of the game I already have.

Comment: Don't the cartridges save the game?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely not: only if you yourself delete it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer specifically for Pokémon Black/White, but I've moved several NDS/3DS game cartridges between different DS-family devices, and have never lost a save game, ever. That includes Pokémon HeartGold and Y.

Answer (score 0):

DS and 3DS physical cartridges store the save data on the cart itself. Because of this, it will be retained regardless of what console you play it on. (Of course, this can sometimes be false if you are playing on a fake cartridge, which likely isn't the case.)

In short, yes, your save will be retained.